# Add header to response if requested version is deprecated

Tags: c#, .net-core

I would like to add a custom header to my service's response if a deprecated version is requested.

I already have URL-based versioning set up using `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Versioning`, and I additionally have an existing custom `ActionFilter` class that can write custom headers into the response. I can also get the version requested by the client using `context.HttpContext.GetRequestedApiVersion()` inside my `ActionFilter`'s definition for `OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext context)`.

However, I'm not sure how I can check whether the requested version is a deprecated version or not from my custom ActionFilter. The [documentation on deprecating a service version](https://github.com/microsoft/aspnet-api-versioning/wiki/Deprecating-a-Service-Version) does not answer this question and I can't find the answer among any of the rest of the documentation on github.

My controller class is annotated as follows:

```
[ApiVersion("2", Deprecated=true)]
[Route("api/v{v:apiVersion}/[action]")]
[ApiController]
public class CustomControllerV2 : ControllerBase { ... }

[ApiVersion("3")]
[Route("api/v{v:apiVersion}/[action]")]
[ApiController]
public class CustomControllerV3 : ControllerBase { ... }
```

And this is my custom ActionFilter:

```
public class CustomActionFilter : IActionFilter
{
    public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context) {
        // not implemented
    }

    public void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext context) {
        var requestedApiVersion = context.HttpContext.GetRequestedApiVersion();
        if (
            // Check whether version is deprecated here
        ) {
            context.HttpContext.Response.Headers.Add("warning", "Requested version "+requestedApiVersion.ToString()+" is deprecated.");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the incoming request you will see what the URL is, and therefore you can determine which controller it will be mapped to. Controllers are classes, and the deprecated ones are marked with the `[ApiVersion(Deprecated = true)]` attribute. So you can grab the controller, and with reflection you can check its attributes and see if it's deprecated. Documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/attributes/accessing-attributes-by-using-reflection)